# Import a ffprobe json metadata file into a video file

Tags: json, import, ffmpeg, metadata, ffprobe

I've used ffprobe to export the metadata from a video file as a JSON file (metadata.json) and then removed several chapters from the JSON metadata file using jq metadata_clean.json.

I'm now looking for a way to import the JSON metadata file (metadata_clean.json) back into the video file.

I've looked at ffmpeg but it appears to only accept its own standard metadata file format.

Any suggestions appreciated, thanks.

Comment: ffmpeg can't do that. If you want to spice videos, you must use an NLE, or a series of ffmepg commands with time ranges.

Comment: @sztmary I'm only looking to change the metadata and re-import it. Not looking to edit the video or splice it.

Comment: I am also looking for a way to edit the metadata (specifically chapters names) without encoding the stream.